# Short PC Motherboard with Raspberry Pi

Tags: remote

I am wondering if there is any way to use the raspberry pi to short the power pins on my desktop's motherboard. I don't know much about electricity and wiring. Can I use the GPIO and wires for this, or would I need to buy an electrical component/circuit?

Comment: Sorry, just realised my mistake ... you'd probably want to use some component/circuit - to protect both your pi and computer from each other

Comment: Not clear what do you mean by "short".  Possible meanings are: (1) "borrow" 5V (or also 12V, 3V3) from the PC's ATX12V2x power supply, so you don't need to use a wall wart, (2) Switch on and off the ATX PSU and also check if power is on or not, (3) ... You can wiki atx for more details - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX You can use just one Rpi GPIO pin, preferably with optocoupler to isolate and step up Rpi 3V3 logic signal to 5V to control the PSU's pin 16 (green wire) of the 24pin plug.  If what you want is 5V, then all the 5 red wires give you 5V.  You can directly use any of all of them.

Comment: I presume "short" in this case means simply "create a short circuit between", and I guess the pins in question are the power BUTTON pins, which cause the machine to be powered on/off, rather than actual power pins - is that correct?